# The titlesec package gives an error once section is encountered

Tags: sectioning

In the code/text below, the titlesec package gives an error. I would be thankful for any comments on how to fix that.

Thank you very much for the help.

The error message is:

! Package titlesec Error: No format for this command.

See the titlesec package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...

l.270 \section{test}

If you (re)set the class of a sectioning command, you may
you may need to (re)define its format with \titleformat

! Missing number, treated as zero.

}
l.270 \section{test}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number, look up` weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

}
l.270 \section{test}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.

}
l.270 \section{test}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number, look up` weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

}
l.270 \section{test}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,
headsepline,     unknownkeysallowed % Linie fuer Kopfzeile
]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headings=optiontohead}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% Druckbereich: \areaset[BCOR]{textwidth}{textheight}
% BCOR ist "Binding Correction", also wieviel Innenrand verloren geht
% A4 hat 297mm x 210mm
% wenn keine Marginalien, dann ist Breite 15cm vielleicht besser
\areaset[1.5cm]{15cm}{25cm}
    
%% Die folgende Zeile sorgt dafuer, dass die Fussnoten eingerueckt werden,
%% und zwar um 2em (class scrbook).
    
\deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{[\thefootnotemark]}}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{[\thefootnotemark]}}
    
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}
    
\usepackage{float}
    
\usepackage{verbatim}
    

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{boldline, multirow}

\usepackage{caption}   
\usepackage{keyval}    

\usepackage[english]{babel}    % english titles (Figure,Table,...)
% Ansonsten 'german' einsetzen


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


%\usepackage{thumbpdf}          % include page preview thumbnails FIXME

%% Unterstuetzung fuer Graphiken und Farben
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex,table]{xcolor}
%\definecolor{DSblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.9}   % example defining a color

% cross referencing and hyperrefs
\usepackage[                % FIXME explain
pdftex,                  % Ausgabe-Medium: PDF
colorlinks=true,         % farbige Links in der Bildschirm-Version?
pdfstartview=FitV,       % wie soll Acrobat starten?
linkcolor=black,         % Farbe fuer Querverweise
citecolor=black,         % Farbe fuer Zitierungen
urlcolor=black,          % Farbe fuer Links
bookmarks=true
]{hyperref}

%% Bibliography wird im Inhaltsverzeichnis angezeigt, aber ohne Nummer;
%% notlot zusaetzlich waere no list of tables; notlof zusaetzlich waere no list of
%% figures



%% leere Seiten des Inhaltsverzeichnis usw. bekommen keine Kopf und Fusszeile
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{multido}    % FIXME ???????????
\usepackage{everysel}   % FIXME ???????????

%% besserer Flattersatz: \RaggedRight
\usepackage{ragged2e}




\hypersetup{
pdfauthor = {Bernhard Boehmler},
pdftitle = {Trivial source character tables of small finite groups},
pdfsubject = {representation theory of finite groups},
pdfkeywords = {representation theory},
pdfcreator = {LaTeX with hyperref package},
pdfproducer = {pdflatex}
}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array,blkarray}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{arcs}

\usepackage{typearea}





\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012D}{\u{\i}}

\usepackage{sagetex}

% \bibliography{Biblio} 



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}


\def\mystrut{\scalebox{1.4}{\strut}}


\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pzc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][\
arraystretch]{%
\edef\arraystretch{#1}%
\hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
\makeatother





\newtheoremstyle{dotless}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{dotless}

\setcounter{section}{1}

%\swapnumbers
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]
%\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\numberwithin{Theorem}{section}
\newtheorem{Example}[Theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{Proposition}[Theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Definition}[Theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Lemma}[Theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Korollar}[Theorem]{Korollar}
%\newtheorem{Theorem}[example]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{examples}[Theorem]{Examples}
\newtheorem{Satz}[Theorem]{Satz}
\newtheorem{Anwendung}[Theorem]{Anwendung}
\newtheorem*{Beweis*}{Beweis}
\newtheorem*{Beweis der Bemerkung*}{Beweis der Bemerkung:}
\newtheorem{Bemerkung}[Theorem]{Bemerkung}
\newtheorem*{Definition (Direkte Summe)*}{Definition (Direkte Summe)}
\newtheorem*{Bemerkung*}{Bemerkung}
\newtheorem*{Bemerkungen*}{Bemerkungen}
\newtheorem*{Beispiel*}{Beispiel}
\newtheorem*{Beispiele*}{Beispiele}
\newtheorem*{Korollar*}{Korollar}
\newtheorem{Korollar123}[Theorem]{Korollar}
\newtheorem{Korollar12345}[Theorem]{Korollar}



\newtheorem{Green}[Theorem]{Theorem (Green correspondence)}
\newtheorem{definition}[Theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[Theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{lemmaFischbacher}[Theorem]{Fischbacher's reduction lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[Theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{theorem}[Theorem]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[Theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{proof of the remark*}{Proof of the remark:}
\newtheorem{remark}[Theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem*{remark*}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{remarks*}{Remarks}
\newtheorem*{example*}{Example}
\newtheorem*{examples*}{Examples}
\newtheorem*{corollary*}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{corollary123}[Theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{corollary12345}[Theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}


\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
\pushQED{\qed}%
\normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
\trivlist
\item[\hskip\labelsep
\itshape
#1\@addpunct{.}]\mbox{}\par\noindent\ignorespaces
}{%
\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother



\newcommand{\properideal}{%
\mathrel{\ooalign{$\lneq$\cr\raise.22ex\hbox{$\lhd$}\cr}}}



\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<-> mathx10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}


\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{zavm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheart}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{86}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vardiamond}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{87}



\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{TESTCHAPTER}

\section{test}

asd

\end{document}
```

Comment: your example is way too long, but normally you shouldn't use the titlesec package together with a KOMA-class.